# Foreach values in sequential order

Tags: php

I currently get back data from an API in an array like:

```
Array ( [Play] => 0,0 
        [SE] => 10,10 
        [AW] => 1,1 
        [ID] => 2949038,2947560 
        [status] => 1 
        [Name] => txt1,txt2 ) 1
```

To get the ID values I just use a basic foreach:

```
   $ids = explode(',', $userQrLt['ID']);

   foreach($ids as $id) {
       echo "http://thewebsite.com/cgi-bin/zd_view.cgi?q=" . $id . "<br />";
   }
```

I also need the "**Name**" values, the ids are in order, meaning, 2949038 goes with txt1 and 2947560 goes with txt2, I know I could do another for each, but is there a way I could grab both values with the 1 for each?

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, with foreach you can also grab the index, and use it to get the other part:

```
$ids = explode(',', $userQrLt['ID']);
$names = explode(',', $userQrLt['Name']);

foreach($ids as $index => $id) {
    $name = $names[$index]; // but not sure what you want to do with it..
    echo "http://thewebsite.com/cgi-bin/zd_view.cgi?q=" . $id . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the `for` loop

```
$ids = explode(',', $userQrLt['ID']);
$names = explode(',', $userQrLt['Name']);
foreach($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++) {
    echo "http://thewebsite.com/cgi-bin/zd_view.cgi?q=".$ids[$i]."&name=$names[$i]<br />";
}
```